# Virtualization BIOS setting Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, bios

So, I want to enable Virtualization in the BIOS to get VirtualBox working on my Windows 10 PC.

I successfully made it into the BIOS, from the Settings app. On Youtube tutorials on how to change the visualization setting, it is made for Windows 8, and the person goes into Advanced Settings.

I cannot find that option. Anywhere.

How possibly can I enable visualization on my Windows 10?

Here is a Bios Image:

[image: http://imgur.com/XBKMGtU]

Lenovo G50-45 Windows 10 AMD Radeon R2 64-bit (x64)

Comment: Umm... you mean "*Virtual*ization"?

Comment: Um. It said so on every site I visited that had the same problem as me. To enable Virtualization on BIOS. I basically have VirtualBox, running on a 64-bit OS, but I can't see any 64-bit options, only 32-bit.

Comment: I think he’s referring to your typo (of sorts) throughout the post. :D

Comment: I think I spelt everything right...?

Comment: You said *visualization*, not *virtual*ization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is called “AMD SVM Support”. SVM (Secure Virtual Machine) is AMD’s take on Intel’s VT-x.

Comment: Wasn't it called AMD-x?

Comment: Nope, there is no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

Go into Windows Control Panel (search for Control Panel in toolbar if you can't find it), and select programs.  Then select Turn Windows features on and off.

Make sure Hyper V is turned OFF (blank) and reboot if needed.

Windows 10 by default enables Hyper-V, which blocks any other 64bit virtualization.

ps - if you want to get two cores running, set memory in virtualbox, and set key ports forwarded add this to your virtualbox file

```
# Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  vb.memory = "3000"
  vb.cpus = "2"
end

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

Comment: worked like a charm for me on Windows 10.